# How do you isolate each number in an int and put it into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, int

For example, let's say the user enters: 2314. What is the quickest way to take each number and put it in its own field in the array?

I have tried converting into a string and then isolating each number as a char, but I don't know how to convert it from a char into an int.

Comment: "it's own field in the array" means?

Comment: Show  your efforts before the question will be closed..

Comment: I have tried converting into a string and then isolating each number as a char, but I don't know how to convert it from a char into an int.

Comment: @PermGenError. Nope. That will give ASCII code of that number. See my answer for proper way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can convert your number to string.
2. Then convert the string to a char array, using `String#toCharArray()` method.
3. Create an `int[]` of size equal to char array.
4. Iterate over char array, and convert each character to int, and put it in integer array.

*Remember*, converting `char` to `int` is *tricky*. You **can't** just do a *typecast*. That will give you *ASCII* code of the number. You can use following code to convert from `char` to `int`:

```
char ch = '3';
int chToInt = ch - '0';
```

---

Alternative way is to use an `ArrayList`. And do integer *division* and *modulus* operations, to get each individual digit, and add it to `ArrayList`.

```
2314 / 1000 = 2     // First digit (add to ArrayList)
2314 % 1000 = 314  // This is the new number 

314 / 100 = 3   // Add this to ArrayList
314 % 100 = 14  // This is the new number

// Proceed like this
```

You need to find a way to write a `loop` for the above steps.

Comment: What does subtracting by char '0' do?

Comment: @user2396852. `'2' - '0'`, will subtract the ASCII code of both the characters. And the difference will be `2`.

Comment: 314 / 100 = 14 should be 314 % 100 = 14. I can't edit this myself since a 1 character change for correctness is not considered substantial.

Comment: @andrew.rockwell Thanks Andrew. Edited it.

Answer (score 2):

```
int number = 1234;
int array[] = new int[String.valueOf(number).length()];
for (int i = 0; number > 0; i++) {
    array[i] = number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prints the integer a in reverse order(lsb to msb)

```
while(a > 0)
{
    arr[i] = a%10;
    a = a/10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] nums = new int[input.length];
int i = 0;
for (String c : input.split("(?<=.)")
    nums[i++] = Integer.parseInt(c);
```

The split regex is the key: It's a "look behind" for any character, which causes a split after every character.

If you split simply on a blank, ie `str.split("")`, there is s blank in the first element of the resulting array.

Comment: i guess ~OP wants to populate an int array. BTW, thanks for remainding me about str#split("") which produces an empty string at index 0. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
    String str="2314";
    int[] arr=new int[str.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i,i+1));
    }
```